# wp_dropdown_roles() to replace option value = code

Tags: plugin-development, user-roles

I'm trying to replace a hardcoded dropdown list of roles in a plugin. Currently this is the code:

```
echo '<select name="xf_user_role_' . $id . '" id="xf_user_role_' . $id . '">';
?>

<option value='subscriber'
<?php echo ($xf_options['xf_user_role'][$id] == 'subscriber') ? "selected='yes'" : ''; ?> >Subscriber</option>

<option value='contributor'
<?php echo ($xf_options['xf_user_role'][$id] == 'contributor') ? "selected='yes'" : ''; ?> >Contributor</option>

<option value='author'
<?php echo ($xf_options['xf_user_role'][$id] == 'author') ? "selected='yes'" : ''; ?> >Author</option>

<option value='editor'
<?php echo ($xf_options['xf_user_role'][$id] == 'editor') ? "selected='yes'" : ''; ?> >Editor</option>

<option value='administrator'
<?php echo ($xf_options['xf_user_role'][$id] == 'administrator') ? "selected='yes'" : ''; ?> >Administrator</option>

</select>
```

This code is changed to :

```
echo '<select name="xf_user_role_' . $id . '" id="xf_user_role_' . $id . '">';
wp_dropdown_roles( );
?>
</select>
```

The dropdown list shows but selecting doesn't give the $xf_options ...

[The wp_dropdown_roles isn't well documented in the Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_roles). I've tried a few different ways to add information into the () but am not getting it right.

What is the proper information for within the ()?

Answer (score 0):

The `wp_dropdown_roles()` function internally uses [`get_editable_roles()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_editable_roles/) to fetch the needed roles. It does nothing else than fetching the roles from the global:

```
$all_roles = $GLOBALS['wp_roles']->roles;
```

and filter it afterwards:

```
return apply_filters( 'editable_roles', $all_roles );
```

So you can simply add the following function to a plugin or your `functions.php` file of your theme:

```
function wpse137935_filter_editable_roles( Array $roles )
{
    // Don't conflict and remove immediately
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    // Do any logic in here that appends or removes roles

    return $roles;
}
```

Then, right before the call to `wp_dropdown_roles()`, you add:

```
add_filter( 'editable_roles', 'wpse137935_filter_editable_roles' );
```

It's important that you add the filter as late as possible to not crash into other plugins or your theme if they/it calls the same function elsewhere.